# socket.io setinterval way

Tags: socket.io

I want to make a web page for give the client the news of his friends every 1 second using socket.io + node.js.

My codes  :

**Client :**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:port');
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('hello', 'Hello guest');
});
socket.on('news_by_server', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('news', 'I want news :D ');
}, 1000);
```

**server:**

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(port);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('hello', function(data){
            console.log('new client connected');
        });
        socket.on('news', function(data){
            socket.emit('news_by_server', 1);
        });
    });
```

that's the mains codes, but my question is about the INTERVAL, is it good the make realtime news or there's a way better then it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no need for the client to ask for news. You can force the server if you want to emit every 1 second - as long as there are clients connected, they will receive updates. If there are no clients connected, you will see in the logs that nothing happens.

On the server

```
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('news_by_server', 'Cow goes moo'); 
}, 1000);
```

On the client

```
socket.on('news_by_server', function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, That what I want to looking for

Comment: When you write `socket.emit( ... `, on the server, what is `socket`? I get an error saying that `socket` isn't defined.. Thanks

Comment: io.sockets.on('connection', function (_socket_) {

Comment: Would it not save money to only emit at interval when a client requests such data using an event for a specific page. Could you not then clear these intervals on page changes ?

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much the standard way to do it. If you've not already looked the [example apps](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) page on socket.io, there's a beibertweet example that does just this using setInterval.

Also there's a [slightly more advanced example](http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/learning-node-js-socket-io-a-simple-streaming-example/) on this blog.

Plus .. I found [Ryan Dahls's intro](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I) on YouTube really useful for understanding the basics of node operation.

Hope that helps.