# Send massage based on some interval in Node JS Websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm new to Node JS. I wrote NodeJs code it is working fine. But is sending when send a message from a client but I want to send message repeated manner.

Send response when client send any message:

```
var webSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var webSocketServerObject = new webSocketServer({ port: 9060 });

webSocketServerObject.on('connection', function (socketObject) {
  socketObject.on('message', function (message) {
  console.log('The' + message + 'Message Received from \n from IP ' + socketObject.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress);
  socketObject.send("Received " + message);
});

 socketObject.on('close', function (c, d) {
  console.log('Disconnect ' + c + ' -- ' + d);
 });

});
```

Above code is working fine([reference](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1220/create-web-socket-server-nodejs-for-real-time) ) same code I modified based on interval but it not working.
Below modification:

```
webSocketServerObject.on('connection', function (socketObject) {
  setInterval(function(){
    socketObject.send("Hello...");
  }, 10000);    
  socketObject.on('close', function (c, d) {
    console.log('Disconnect ' + c + ' -- ' + d);
  });
});
```

How I can make it in sever to keep sending messages.

Comment: You want that at a specific interval of time server keep sending a message to the client?

Comment: @HarshPatel - yeah

Comment: I would recommend http://socket.io for this. However, i think you should at least clear the interval if the connection is closed...

Comment: Here setInterval will call that block of code after a time specified by you. It will not keep calling that block of code.

Comment: Please understand I'm new and this is my first Nodejs code

Comment: THis might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240863/7844349